# Want to add predicted day's other variables (except one variable) during training with LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, lstm

I am working on an electricity price prediction project. I am using a window of 15 days where the 15th days' price is predicted based on the prior 14 days. This is time-series data and I have 15 variables in my dataset including the price. Now, this is predicting the 15th-day price(hourly) based on the previous 14 days(hourly) data. This data includes all 15 variables. What I am trying to do is that I want to consider some variables like wind, temperature, etc from the 15th day when predicting the 15th days' price.  I have all 15 variables for the 15th day but I want to use a few of them during training to predict the 15th days' price. I am struggling to implement the idea!

I am using the LSTM network for training purposes. I am sharing the code of the window setup which works with train, validation, and test data.

Please suggest to me how should I modify this WindowGenerator() function to serve my purpose. How can I implement this idea in my code? Thanks in advance...

```
class WindowGenerator():
  def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift,
               train_df=train_df, val_df=val_df, test_df=test_df,
               label_columns=None):
    # Store the raw data.
    self.train_df = train_df
    self.val_df = val_df
    self.test_df = test_df

    # Work out the label column indices.
    self.label_columns = label_columns
    if label_columns is not None:
      self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                                    enumerate(label_columns)}
    self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                           enumerate(train_df.columns)} # only consider train dataset

    # Work out the window parameters.
    self.input_width = input_width
    self.label_width = label_width
    self.shift = shift

    self.total_window_size = input_width + shift

    self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
    self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]

    self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
    self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
    self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]

  def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join([
        f'Total window size: {self.total_window_size}',
        f'Input indices: {self.input_indices}',
        f'Label indices: {self.label_indices}',
        f'Label column name(s): {self.label_columns}'])



OUT_STEPS = 24
INPUT_WIDTH = 336
w1 = WindowGenerator(input_width=INPUT_WIDTH, label_width=OUT_STEPS, shift=OUT_STEPS, label_columns=['Price'])


# split window

def split_window(self, features):
  inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
  labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
  if self.label_columns is not None:
    labels = tf.stack(
        [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],axis=-1)

  inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
  labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

  return inputs, labels

WindowGenerator.split_window = split_window


example_window = tf.stack([np.array(test_df[:w1.total_window_size])])
example_inputs, example_labels = w1.split_window(example_window)

print('All shapes are: (batch, time, features)')
print(f'Window shape: {example_window.shape}')
print(f'Inputs shape: {example_inputs.shape}')
print(f'labels shape: {example_labels.shape}')
```

Comment: This is only the first half of the `WindowGenerator` code, to make it work, you need to finish writing the second half. Please read the whole data windowing section: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

Comment: Thank you, Jason. I add the remaining part. Still, I am confused about how should I modify the "WindowGenerator()" to implement the idea!

Comment: Did you find any solution?